# Image Processing Performance iOS Apps

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, metalkit

More of a general interest question relating to iOS. I’m interested in image processing and I’m wondering if anyone has any inkling how these apps (sample images below) manage to perform seemingly very compute intensive actions such as pixel sorting in a very responsive way.

Are they using Core Image filters? Perhaps leveraging Metal?

[image]

Comment: The gif is really fast and it's hard to see what's going on. Can you please post single images of the effects you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommending using Metal, more opportunity for optimisations.